# C++ Aware duplication insert into a std::map

Tags: c++, hash, insert, duplicates, stdmap

I have a question about inserting something to a std::map in C++.

Thats my Code sofar:

stringutils.hh:

...

```
  unsigned long hashSDBM(char *strToHash){
      unsigned char* str = new unsigned char[strlen(strToHash) + 1];
      strncpy( (char *) str, strToHash, strlen(strToHash) );

      unsigned long hash = 0;
      int c;

      while ((c = *str++)){
          hash = c + (hash <<6) + (hash <<16) - hash;
      }

      return hash;
  }
```

...

hashmap.hh

```
#include "stringutils.hh"

namespace{

using namespace std;

class MapElement{

    private:
        char* filename;
        char* path;

    public:
        MapElement(char* f, char* p):filename(f), path(p){}
        ~MapElement(){
           delete [] filename;
           delete [] path;
        }
        char* getFileName(){ return filename; }
        char* getPath(){ return path; }

};


class HashMap{

    private:
        map<long*, MapElement*> *hm;

        long hash(char* key);

    public:
        HashMap(){
           hm = new map<long*, MapElement*>();
        }
        ~HashMap(){
           delete hm;
        }
        long put(char* k, MapElement *v);
};

long HashMap::hash(char* key){
  return stringutils::hashSDBM(key);
}


long HashMap::put(char* k, MapElement *v){
  long *key = new long();
  *key = hash(k);
  pair<map<long*,MapElement*>::iterator, bool> ret;
  ret = hm->insert(std::pair<long*, MapElement*>(key, v));

  if(ret.second == false){
    cerr<<"Already exists: "<<ret.first->second->getFileName()<<endl;
    return *key;
  }
  cerr<<"INSERTED "<<*key<<endl;
  return 0;
}
```

main.cc:

```
HashMap *hm = new HashMap();


int main(void){

  MapElement *m1; 

  char a[] = "hello";
  char b[] = "world";
  m1 = new MapElement(a,b);
  hm->put(a, m1);

  char c[] = "thats";
  char d[] = "a test";
  m1 = new MapElement(c,d);
  hm->put(c, m1);

  char e[] = "hello";
  char f[] = "test";
  m1 = new MapElement(e,f);
  hm->put(e, m1);

  return 0;
}
```

It's compiles whitout any errors or warnings and when I start it, the following output is generatéd:

INSERTED 7416051667693574450

INSERTED 8269306963433084652

INSERTED 7416051667693574450

Why does the second insert off the key "hello" doesnt have any effect?

Comment: You should explain what your code does, instead of just pasting it.

Comment: Your code (function `hashSDBM`) leaks memory. You should use `std::string` instead of raw `char *` strings.

Comment: This code has serious resource management problems. The `HashMap` destructor doesn't release the memory allocated for all the keys and values. The `MapElement` destructor never gets called but if it did it would segfault because it blindly calls `delete[]` on pointers to automatic variables not dynamically allocated memory. Neither class correctly handles copying or assignment. Please stop using `pointers` and `new`.

Answer (score 2):

The keys in the `std::map` are unique. If you want to allow duplicate keys, use `std::multimap`. The map::insert you're using returns a pair of iterator and a `bool`. The bool indicates if the insertion has actually inserted or not (not if the key was already there).

Answer (score 1):

> Why does the second insert of the key doesnt have any effect?

Your key is a pointer, and two pointers to different `long` objects that have the same value are different keys. You would really help yourself by not using pointers so excessively. C++ is not Java.

Comment: [MAP-doc](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/map/insert/)
if ret->second == false, than the key already exists! 
I DON'T want multiple keys, but I want to recognize wether a key already exists!

Comment: @Hymir disregard my previous answer.

Answer (score 0):

Goodness... please read a good C++ book before going any further, there are good books recommended in the C++ tag description.

---

So, the issue here is that your code uses pointers... everywhere... and pointers do not behave like you think they do. Many languages such as Java have pervasive reference types: everything is just a reference. C++ is not such a language, it makes a big difference between pointers/references on the one hand and values on the other.

In your specific case, `long*` is a pointer to a `long`. As far as `map` is concerned, two distinct pointers are just that: **distinct**, no matter the value of what they point to.

So... we need to get rid of those pointers. Everywhere. And stop using C idioms in C++.

---

> stringutils.hh

```
  unsigned long hashSDBM(std::string const& strToHash){
      unsigned long hash = 0;

      for (char c: strToHash) {
          hash = c + (hash <<6) + (hash <<16) - hash;
      }

      return hash;
  }
```

In short:

- don't use raw `char*` in C++, memory ownership is unclear which leads to leaks/dangling pointers
- use `const` appropriately, a function that does not modify its argument should take `const` references to them
- use C++11 for style loops, they are as efficient as manual code whilst being much easier to read and much more harder to screw up

---

> hashmap.hh

```
namespace HashMap {

class MapElement{
public:
    MapElement(std::string f, std::string p):
        filename(f), path(p) {}

    std::string const& getFileName() const { return filename; }
    std::string const& getPath() const { return path; }

private:
    std::string filename;
    std::string path;
};
```

Let's start here:

- No anonymous namespaces in headers, it doesn't do what you think it does (read on them)
- No raw pointers
- No fiddling with resources in business classes
- const-correctness matters
- Present the public API first, it's what users are interested in

Onward:

```
class HashMap{
public:
    unsigned long put(std::string const& k, MapElement v);

private:
    static unsigned long hash(std::string const& key);

    std::map<unsigned long, MapElement> hm;
};

inline unsigned long HashMap::hash(std::string const& key){
    return stringutils::hashSDBM(key);
}

inline unsigned long HashMap::put(std::string const& k, MapElement v){
    unsigned long const key = hash(k);

    auto const ret = hm.emplace(key, v);

    if (ret.second == false){
        std:: cerr << "Already exists: " << ret.first->second.getFileName() << "\n";
        return key;
    }
    std::cerr << "INSERTED " << key << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Alright...

- No need for so many pointers, the code is simpler without them!
- The internal `hash` function does not access any state, make it `static`
- Declare variables at the last moment possible, and initialize them immediately... it let you use `auto` rather than name overly complicated types explicitly
- `std::endl` does not do what you think it does (hint: it flushes the buffer! Slowest possible I/O operation!), just use plain `"\n"` instead

Further notes:

- Why let the user submit the key, if said key has to be the filename? You can read it from the `MapElement` object instead... or print the `key` (and not the filename) when there is a collision, in case they differ
- Hashes are not unique, if two different filenames hash to the same number you will reject the second... you should use a composite key (hash + filename)
- You return `0` when inserting, and `key` when not... but nothing prevents the key from being `0` so receiving a `0` leaves the user doubting what happened

---

> main.cpp

```
int main(void){
    HashMap::HashMap hm;

    hm.put("hello", MapElement("hello", "world"));
    hm.put("thats", MapElement("thats", "a test"));
    hm.put("hello", MapElement("hello", "test"));

    return 0;
}
```

And for the finish:

- Avoid globals
- No need to name all temporaries